# After installing Lubuntu, Windows XP does not boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows, lubuntu

I recently successfully installed and ran Lubuntu alongside Windows XP. However when I tried to boot Windows XP, I got the following error message:

```
Windows could not start because the following file is missing or corrupt
 <windows root>\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
Please re-install a copy of the above file.
```

Is there any way to correct this problem without inserting a Windows CD?

Answer (score 0):

With a short google search I found the following solution:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1445839

They are referencing 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314477/en-us